# Trying to open a preexisting file so that it can be seen on google chrome

Tags: html

I am trying to see how my code will be displayed on a browser, but I do not know how to access it in Google Chrome.

I am trying to get something like this:

[image]

Comment: Right-click 'Open With... --> Google Chrome'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Right click the file and select, Open with google chrome.
2. Or you can paste the file path in address bar of chrome. Since it index.html you wont need file name at the end of file path, else the file path should end with file name.